# Send a JSON Post request in CEF

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

So, I'm just going to get to the point;
Basically I'm trying to send a POST request in JSON Format, and not Form which is the default in CEFSharp.
I've been looking around for hours, trying to find how to send a JSON request but so far found nothing

Comment: Start with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#load-url-with-postdata you should only need to make minimum changes to the example. Use DevTools to inspect a JSON post request to see what headers etc are required.

Comment: @amaitland that solved it, thanks